# Where does "Non-Click" Behaviour fit into a MVVM Application?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I can expose ICommands from my ViewModels but where does Non-Click/Command behaviour fit into a MVVM Application? eg. Drag & Drop, Hover etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post:

http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2009/07/21/728.aspx

Shows how you can still use the MVVM pattern effectively for "Non-Click / Command" behaviour such as drag / drop.

Comment: Could you explain the basic structure of the app? I don't really understand the workings of that

Answer (score 1):

I would place them in the code-behind because this is UI behaviour, I don't know if it's "right" but I think you shouldn't overcomplicate such easy things.